# NetBeans 8.0.2 "no executable specified in project"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am working on a c++ application and it builds just fine but upon running my main class NetBeans complains that no executable has been specified in my project, it then asks me to provide a path to a .exe file? What is an executable and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

An executable is a file that can be executed. A .exe file is one kind of executable. In general some people would include .bat files, .com files, .jar files with a main class in the manifest, scripts in various languages etc as executable files. In Linux/MAC executable files often have no extension at all.
However, if you are on Windows building with C++ the file you probably want is a .exe file.

If you create a new `C++ Application` type project it should already know which file to run since it will be setup to create it.  If you create a project with `C++ Project with Existing Sources` then the project could create multiple executable files or none at all if the goal was just to build a library. This depends on who ever authored the external Makefile or whatever that project uses. If you don't know and can't guess from looking at the directory ask whoever created the original project or consult their documentation.

Comment: I created a new C++ Dynamic Library? Could that be my problem?

Comment: Yes a library whether static or dynamic can not be executed or run on its own. You can create  a new C++ Application than uses some of the functions in your library and run that but you can not run the library itself.